# How to bind ngModel values into select-searchable options?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

Is there any way to bind ngModel values into select-searchable option in ionic to see default values from localStorage.

```
<ion-col col-6>
        <select-searchable okText="Odaberi" cancelText="Otkaži"
                           class="inputStyle"
                           item-content
                           [(ngModel)]="WarrentItem.deviceManufacturerId"
                           searchFailText="Nema rezultata"
                           [items]="allManufacturers"
                           itemValueField="id"
                           itemTextField="value"
                           [canSearch]="true"
                           (ionClear)="onClear($event)"
                           (onChange)="materialChanged2($event)">

        </select-searchable>

      </ion-col>
```

In this case of code, I've got a list of all manufacturers in options, but I need to get a default value which was set in localStorage while I open this form.. Thanks a lot.

Comment: can you please share what is WarrentItem?

Comment: WarrentItem is an object for array in Localstorage

Answer (score 0):

You can set like this

### html

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label>Port</ion-label>
    <select-searchable
        item-content
        [(ngModel)]="port"
        [items]="ports"
        itemValueField="id"
        itemTextField="name"
        [canSearch]="true"
        (onChange)="portChange($event)">
    </select-searchable>
</ion-item>
```

### ts

```
ports = [
   { id: 1, name: 'Tokai' },
   { id: 2, name: 'Vladivostok' },
   { id: 3, name: 'Navlakhi' }
];
port = {
   id: 3,
   name: 'Navlakhi'
};
```

Comment: That's no solution that I really need.

Comment: Your question says you need to set default value in select-searchable

Comment: I need to catch default values from local storage inside them. Such as AIR CONDITION, now i've got a list of items, but i need to get default value on it. Now, when i open my form, i've got an empty first row of select-searchable. This is similar like binding in ion-input {{anyItem}} if you know what i mean.

Comment: Here I am setting port values as object so you need to get item from local storage and compare with your list of available items and get whole object and assign it

Comment: How to assign it? I've got items from local storage into the list.

Comment: Need to do something like *NgFor instead of that to show default value.

Comment: Please create stackbliz example